# CMAKE LLAMA CPP Binding PIP Installation giving error

Tags: python, cmake, pip, langchain, llamacpp

Trying to install llama-cpp-python as depicted on MAC using METAL. However, it is giving the following error as depicted in the screenshot. Could someone help?

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/llamacpp

[image: Pycharm Python Console Error]

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent *textual* information. Instead, paste the error message as **text**. See e.g. [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.